# Can't change currency symbol on spree 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, currency

I'm currently using Spree 3.0 and changed my currency to Colombian Peso (COP). Right now prices are shown like this: ₱80.000,00. I want them to look like this:  $ 80.000. I have an idea on how to remove the two 0 after the comma but haven't been able to change the currency symbol for $. This is what I have so far:

in /config/initializers/spree.rb

```
Spree.config do |config|

  config.logo = 'templo samadhi logo.png'
  config.admin_interface_logo = 'templo samadhi logo.png'
  country = Spree::Country.find_by_name('Colombia')
  config.default_country_id = country.id if country.present?
  config.checkout_zone = country.id

Money::Currency.register({
   :priority        => 1,
   :iso_code        => "COP",
   :iso_numeric     => country.id,
   :name            => "Colombia",
   :symbol          => "$ ",
   :subunit         => "Cent",
   :subunit_to_unit => 100,
   :separator       => ".",
   :delimiter       => ","
})
end
```

This is somehow working because the ₱ symbol is getting removed but the $ is not showing up.

I appreciate if someone can help me with this.

**UPDATE**

I added the following and now I'm removing the two 0 after the comma but I'm also getting a $ after the price like this: 80.000 $.

So right now I don't know how to move the $ symbol before the price.

```
Spree::Money.class_eval do
  def to_s
    formatted = @money.format(@options)
    formatted.gsub(/,00/, "")
    formatted.symbol_position == :before
  end

  def to_html(options = { :html => true })
    to_s
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using this solution but found an issue when I try to process the payment through the stripe gateway, it actually needs the amount subunit to be "Cents" in order to make the currency conversion.

With the @luisjar answer you actually don't use subunits in the COP currency but they may be needed for some payment gateways like stripe. In order to use the COP currency (or any other currency) with a subunit but without showing it, you need to set the format property no_cents true. This is the way I show the amount in Colombian Peso currency like $ 10,000 COP.

```
Spree.config do |config|

  #Change currency symbol for Colombia
  country = Spree::Country.find_by_name('Colombia')
  config.default_country_id = country.id if country.present?
  config.checkout_zone = country.id


  Spree::Money.class_eval do
    def to_s
      @money.format.gsub(/,00/, "")
      @money.format(:symbol_position => :before, :with_currency => true, :no_cents => true)
    end

    def to_html(options = { :html => true })
     to_s
    end
  end

  Money::Currency.register({
    :priority        => 1,
    :iso_code        => "COP",
    :iso_numeric     => country.id,
    :name            => "Colombia",
    :symbol          => "$ ",
    :subunit         => "Cent",
    :subunit_to_unit => 100,
    :separator       => ".",
    :delimiter       => ","
  })

  Spree::Price.update_all(currency: 'COP')
end
```

I hope this help to any other confused (like me) with the currencies in Spree.

You can read more about currency format in: https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/blob/master/lib/money/money/formatting.rb

Answer (score 2):

With the code, you merely register another currency. Each product(-variant) has many prices, one per currency. You should make sure, probably in a migration, that all your prices on all your variants are updated to use the correct currency.

```
Spree::Price.update_all(currency: 'COP')
```

If you don't want to loose the Dollar prices, but instead want to add an additional price, you need to edit each one manually, or on a migration.

```
Spree::Price.find_each do |price|
  Spree::Price.create(variant: price.variant, amount: price.amount * 1.337, currency: 'COP')
end
```

Where `1.337` is a conversion factor.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found how to remove the two ceros after the comma, use the $ symbol but still use the Colombian peso Currency. This is the way I did it.

```
Spree.config do |config|

  config.logo = 'templo samadhi logo.png'
  config.admin_interface_logo = 'templo samadhi logo.png'
  country = Spree::Country.find_by_name('Colombia')
  config.default_country_id = country.id if country.present?
  config.checkout_zone = country.id

Spree::Money.class_eval do
  def to_s
    @money.format.gsub(/,00/, "")
    @money.format(:symbol_position => :before)
  end

  def to_html(options = { :html => true })
   to_s
  end
end

Money::Currency.register({
  :priority        => 1,
  :iso_code        => "COP",
  :iso_numeric     => country.id,
  :name            => "Colombia",
  :symbol          => "$ ",
  :subunit         => "Peso",
  :subunit_to_unit => 1,
  :separator       => ".",
  :delimiter       => ","
})

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at documentation of class Currency (in gems/money_6.9.0/lib/money/currency.rb) I found better the following settings:

```
Money::Currency.register({
  :priority        => 1,
  :iso_code        => "COP",
  :iso_numeric     => country.id,
  :name            => "Peso",
  :symbol          => "$",
  :html_entity     => "&dollar; ",
  :symbol_first    => true,
  :subunit         => "Cent",
  :subunit_to_unit => 100,
  :separator       => ".",
  :delimiter       => ","
})
```

The "name" attribute is the name of the currency, not the name of the country. The space between the $ and the number goes inside the "html_entity" and not in the symbol. Finally, the "symbol_first" attribute controls where to place the symbol.